# How to Render the container1 Block in controller

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, blocks, catalog, render

I have try this code in controller to render the block.

```
$layout         = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$block_header  = $layout->createBlock('core/template_facade');
$block_header->setDataByKey('alias_in_layout','container1');
$block_header->setDataByKeyFromRegistry('options_container','product');
$block_header->append('product.info.options.wrapper');
$block_header->append('product.info.options.wrapper.bottom');
echo $block_header->toHtml();
```

But its doesn't render the blocks.

And my layout file is

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
   <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
   <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
   <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
   <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</block>
```

how can i render block.

Assist me.

Comment: have tried this on other controller except products controlles

Comment: Yes, I tired in my custom controller.

Answer (score 2):

This code from the catalog xml moves the `product.info.options.wrapper` and `product.info.options.wrapper.bottom` blocks to the container but it does not create them.

This is the code that creates them (from the base/default theme):

```
<reference name="content">

    ...

    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
        <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
        <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
        <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
    </block>
            <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
        </block>
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
        <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
        <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
        <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
        <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
    </block>

    ...

</reference>
```